# drupal 7 date_popup default value does not display

Tags: date, drupal-7, drupal-forms

I am using drupal 7 date_popup field type for my form:

```
    $form['departure_date_1']= array(
    '#type' => 'date_popup',
     '#date_format' => 'Y-m-d',
    '#defalut_value'=>date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date_part1)),
);
```

$date_part1 is string:"2014-03-12", i use strtotime to convert it to date. i also tried:

```
 $form['departure_date_1']= array(
    '#type' => 'date_popup',
     '#date_format' => 'Y-m-d',
    '#defalut_value'=>date('Y-m-d'),
);
```

Or:

```
$form['departure_date_1']= array(
    '#type' => 'date_popup',
     '#date_format' => 'Y-m-d',
    '#defalut_value'=>'2014-03-12',
);
```

none of them works, the filed is blank all the time, i searched the whole day, but still can  not find the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better to go with the core function

```
format_date($date, 'custom', $format)
```

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16485564/195812

Answer (score 1):

instead of #defalut_value use #default_value